# How to change the content of akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.repeat from within the Flow

Tags: akka-stream

I have a piece of code that resembles to the example below:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val mutableList = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

val foo = Source
  .repeat(mutableList)
  .flatMapConcat(myList => Source.fromFuture(Future.successful {
    val foo = new Random().nextInt(10)
    if (myList.contains(foo)) {
      Some(foo)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }))
  .takeWhile(_.isDefined)
  .take(5)
  .collect {
    case Some(value) => value
  }
  .alsoTo(Sink.foreach(value => mutableList.remove(mutableList.indexOf(value))))
  .runFold(List.empty[Int])((list, value) => value +: list)

println(Await.result(foo, Duration.Inf))
}
```

where basically, as a step of the flow, I need to change the content that the source emits.

How can I achieve the same w/o the use a mutable data structure (the ArryBuffer) using akka-stream?

Comment: statefulMapConcat

Comment: @ViktorKlang But isn't  it internal API which is subject to change at any time  ?

Comment: @expert No :) http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@statefulMapConcat[T](f:()=>Out=>scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]